# Inserting more than 16mb document into Mongo db 3.0 using java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I've been evaluating Mongo db 3.0 in java and encountered a scenario where in the document size has exceeded 16MB. The scenario is such that I've a list of primary keys(unique records) which should be in a document as embedded collection with some additional fields. When the pk's exceed 16k, we get the error saying the document size has been exceeded. I know that we can keep the collection outside of the document instead of embedding it, but since it is required in our scenario we have it this way. If we keep it outside of the document as a separate collection, it works fine, but the inserts/updates are  becoming very very slow since it has to search all the pk's and the insert/update.

Is there any other way we can accomplish this?

I know that we can use gridfs for this, but as I've seen the examples it is mainly used for storing the images/videos etc in a file system. This is certainly not how we want to do it.

Any suggestions would be very helpful!!! Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you please re-explain the problem here as you talk about the BSON document limit in the title but your question body talks about primary key limits. These are different things. BTW. It does raise eyebrows when your question is upvoted like this imediately after posting as is quite clearly unclear by the conflicting statements I mention.

Comment: I dint mean primary keys, i have a document which has embedded documents which is more than 16k and exceeding 16MB. I want to store that. How can i come over this?

Comment: Well you just cannot beat the 16MB BSON limit so that is a done point. Primary keys is a different problem, but if it's related to the size of the document there is no point talking about it further. Please stop asking your friends to upvote posts though. It's been noticed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the official documentation :

[MongoDB Limits and Thresholds](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#BSON-Document-Size)

They suggest also to use GridFS when you exceed the size limit of BSON object(16 mbytes). GridFS is not only used for media files, but all kind of binary content.